# Crawling Version Control System

Tags: git, svn, version-control, nutch, web-crawler

I want to crawl some kind of project on GitHub say I want to crawl source code which are created by particular author and bla bla constraints. Is there any plugin for Nutch to crawl this information or best way to get the whole repositories crawled.

I even want to crawl version of publicly hosted version control system using Nutch. Is there any plugin available for the same.

Comment: You cannot crawl remote repositories, you must have a local copy. I don't even know what Nutch is, but the closest you can get to what you ask with core git is arguments to `git log`, see the manpage.

Comment: I think what "user159972" wants is to automatically find a list of all projects that have been created by a particular author, which the same tool will then clone locally.

Answer (score 2):

Github comes with a JSON API. Use the repository API to get the list of repositories for a specific user and then clone them. Should be a matter of a few lines shell.

See the API documentation [here](http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Nutch is a search engine, made by Apache, based on a Lucene backend.

Take a look at github's robots.txt file:
https://github.com/robots.txt

Apart from specific engines, (e.g. google), it says:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Therefore you cannot crawl GitHub with Nutch.

Crawling github with a search engine seems like a bad idea. There will be a lot of similar pages that you would be downloading for no reason. What's wrong with GitHub's search?

Please try to generalise your question. What do you hope to achieve by crawling github with Nutch? What kind of searches are you wanting to perform?

Comment: I think mechanically crawling github is a valid use case. Thus the API.